# How to get the output path of a target defined by ExternalProject?

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, flatbuffers

I'm building Google's FlatBuffers as a dependency for my own project and I need to compile a schema at build-time. I don't want to use `BuildFlatBuffers.cmake` or `FindFlatBuffers.cmake` because I'm using a specific version and I can't rely on it being locally installed.

This is a simplified version of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
ExternalProject_Add (
  flatbuf
  URL "https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/archive/v1.8.0.tar.gz"
  CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
)
add_custom_target (
  flatbuf_schema
  PREFIX ${FLATBUF_PREFIX}
  DEPENDS flatbuf
  COMMAND ${FLATBUF_PREFIX}/src/flatbuf-build/flatc --cpp ${FLATBUF_SCHEMA}
)
```

It works fine for Make and Ninja but fails in Xcode, which builds `flatc` in the `Debug` directory.

I thought about these possible solutions:

- use `add_subdirectory` instead of `ExternalProject_Add` so that I can use `${FLATBUFFERS_FLATC_EXECUTABLE}` or `$<TARGET_FILE:flatc>`;
- manually assign a `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` for `flatbuf`;
- search for `flatc` in multiple paths (not portable; I also don't know how to make it happen at build-time).

I tried (2) and (3) but without success. As for (1), I'm not sure it's a good idea. How can I build schemas in a portable manner?

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue is in Xcode. One thing you could do if you are really stuck is check out what https://github.com/google/fplbase does, as it also depends on FlatBuffers and at least used to build on all platforms equally, including Xcode.

Comment: The problem with Xcode is that it builds flatc in a different directory: instead of having flatc into `flatbuf-build/` it goes into `flatbuf-build/Build/`.

Comment: Not just *build* the external project, but **install** it. The project fully defines its installation layout, a build tool (XCode in your case) doesn't change it.

Comment: That makes sense. So, which variables should I set to make the installation directory the same across all build systems?

Comment: Note: the path to flatc in Xcode is `flatbuf-build/Debug/`, not `flatbuf-build/Build/`. It was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently CMake provides a variable to solve this exact problem, i.e. `CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR` ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR.html)). The path to the `flatc` executable should then be

```
ExternalProject_Get_Property(flatbuf BINARY_DIR)
set (FLATC "${BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/flatc")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExternalProject_Get_Property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_get_property), something like this...

note: I suppose you don't even need to install flatbuf, just build it and use it.

```
ExternalProject_Add (
  flatbuf_project
  URL "https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/archive/v1.8.0.tar.gz"
  CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(flatbuf_project source_dir)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(flatbuf_project binary_dir)

# Export flatbuf executable to consume schema file during build
add_executable(flatbuf::flatbuf IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(flatbuf::flatbuf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    "${binary_dir}/flatc")
add_dependencies(flatbuf::flatbuf flatbuf_project)

add_custom_target(flatbuf_schema
  PREFIX ${FLATBUF_PREFIX}
  COMMAND flatbuf::flatbuff --cpp ${FLATBUF_SCHEMA}
)
```

note2:

> If COMMAND specifies an executable target name (created by the add_executable() command) it will automatically be replaced by the location of the executable created at build time. If set, the CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR executable target property will also be prepended to the command to allow the executable to run on the host. Additionally a target-level dependency will be added so that the executable target will be built before this custom target.

note3: 
target ALIAS are not working on IMPORTED target unfortunately...

Comment: At the end I could do it with `CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR`, but using `ExternalProject_Get_Property` instead of hard-coding the build path is also a good idea.